# Executing an external program with command line args

Tags: java, command, external, args

I need my program to execute a program with command line args and then return the output the program gives.

I've gotten this far, but I haven't quite figured out how to get the command line args in.

```
private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            appendLog("### Command # reboot ###");
            process = new ProcessBuilder(adb.toString() + "reboot");
            process.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process pr = process.start();

            InputStream stream = pr.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

            String line;
            int exit = -1;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                appendLog("### ADB output # Command: reboot ###\n" + line);
                exit = pr.exitValue();
                if (exit == 0) {
                    appendLog("### Process finished # Command: reboot ###\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            appendLog("### ERROR:\n" + ex + " ###");
            appendLog("### Process finished # Command: reboot ###\n");
        }
    }
```

Any help with this matter is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` takes as parameter varargs (undefined number of arguments) where the first argument is the command to be executed (adb, in your case) and followed by arguments.
So, something like, where `adb.toString()` is the full path to adb:

```
process = new ProcessBuilder(adb.toString(), "reboot");
```